# Jquery Ajax post of a form doesn't submit field changes, but only original field values

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, http-post

I'm using Jquery 1.9.1, ASP.NET MVC 3, .Net 4.0 framework, C#, and Targeting IE 8 as the browser client (unfortunately no flex on this requirement).

I have an view in which I'm trying to implement an auto-save feature whereby the data is saved through an ajax call made every so often behind the scenes. The Jquery post works and the data is bound to my model; however, the data sent is the form values as they existed when the page first loaded and does not include any changes made on the page. I'm sure this is a lack of understanding somewhere on my part, but I'm not sure where the breakdown is exactly. My code that performs the post is below. I've verified the data being submitted and that this is an HTTP POST through Fiddler2.

Thoughts?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var postActionUrl = '@Url.Action("AjaxSave", "AjaxPost")';
    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    function AutoSave() {
        $.ajax({
            url: postActionUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            datatype: 'html',
            success: function (result) {
                var txt = "result: " + result.success + " Message: " + result.message;
                alert(txt);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var autoSaveFrequency = "@RulesService.GetAutoSaveIntervalInMiliseconds()";
        alert("Will be saving every " + (autoSaveFrequency) + " seconds.");
        setInterval(AutoSave, autoSaveFrequency);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Anyone care to comment on the numerous down votes here? If you're going to vote down, at least give me some direction as to the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `$('form').serialize()` in the scope of `AutoSave` method. Problem exists as you are serializing you form once and using it repeatably

```
function AutoSave() {
    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: postActionUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function (result) {
            var txt = "result: " + result.success + " Message: " + result.message;
            alert(txt);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: After your 4th edit you finally copypasted my entire answer :)

Comment: @fejesjoco, No mate. __thats no the case__. I was formatting the answer. Yea I provided solution then reasoning. And even in this comments its my 4th edit

Comment: You're both correct, and both getting rep, not much to argue about. Both answers appear to be reached individually, and since there is only one answer to this question, it's expected that both give the same answer.

Comment: I knew it was something stupid like this. Thanks @fejesjoco & @Satpal! Will accept answer once it lets me.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you serialize the form data only once. Move that line inside the autosave function.